# popover won't show title and content

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to create popover but window is not showing data inside popover window.
Window it self is activating.

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign pull-right bottom" data-content="Body content" data-placement="left" title="Title"></i>

<script>
$(function () {
    $('.glyphicon-warning-sign').popover({
        trigger: 'hover',
        delay: {hide: 1000}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DAhU3/9/)

```
$(function () {
    $('.glyphicon-warning-sign').popover({
        trigger: 'hover',
        delay: {hide: 1000},
        title: 'title',
        content: 'content'
    });
});
```